# procrun stopservices method is not getting excuted properly

Tags: java, procrun

I have a weird problem. I am using Apache services to configure my windows services.  As per Procrun,  my batch files should have configured for start and stop services. my problem is when i start my application the start service is executed. but not the stop service. I am bit confused. I am working on this for a long time now. couldn't get it right.. is there any way ?

Answer (score 1):

You could paste a command you used to install the service i.e.
prunsrv //IS//YourService ...

I had some issues with that too.

I have created another thread and when I start the service Thread is starting 
and when I stop the service I set interrupt flag and thread is stopping,
That works OK.

There is an issue with this - if you have some tasks that need to be run i.e. to clean up - they may not be called.
Still struggling with that bit - but I can stop the service no problem.

Comment: No i dnt have any issue with clean up. Struggled with start n stop. But now i did a workaround to fix the issue. I read the PID of my application and saved it ina file. then for stopping read back from that file and fired a console command. Now its working fine.